# What does 40bit - 256 encryption actually mean?

Tags: encryption, ssl, ssl-certificate

I've recently been looking at SSL certificates and have seen a number of vendors selling a low end certificate which encrypts at between 40-256 bits.

However, when I visit a site which has such a certificate it reports that site is using a 256bit encrypted connection.

Since we all know 40bit encryption is now woefully inadequate how can they be offering this as possibility?

It seems as if they are offering something which will range from being completely unsuitable to suitable - is that the case?

Comment: It means absolutely nothing without an algorithm to go with it. RSA? DSA? ECC? AES? DES?

Comment: It's AES in one case but it depends on the browser/client config, right?

Comment: Right, and it has little or nothing to do with the certificate itself. The keys are actually not created by the public/private key pair that belong to the certificate, nor are there normally any hints about what algorithm/protocol to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you mix up two things:

The bit length of the key-pair that belongs to a certificate has nothing to do with the used cipher and it's strength that is used for SSL connections.

The certificate is used for authentication purposes and uses asymmetric cryptography (public and private key forming a key-pair).

The shorter bit lengths you have mentioned are used for encryption of the connection and they are used for symmetric algorithms - their key length is much smaller having an equal security compared to asymmetric crypto algorithms.

Which symmetric algorithm is used for encrypting an SSL connection is negotiated between client and server when the connection starts. Usually the strongest algorithm supported by both sides is used.

Comment: In addition to this, SGC certificates (which are obsolete: don't buy one one those), the shared key size is independent of the public key size in the cert. A good server configuration should disable weak cipher suites.